# how to set default lightning selection for the background of autodesk forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to set a default background color for the forger viewer and want to use lightning selection as in the settings of the viewer. I could not find how can i set default value as in the below settings screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `viewer.setLightPreset()` for that.

The following blog post talks about how to find functions like that:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/change-viewer-settings